# Have I correctly calculated this confidence coefficient?

Tags: statistics

I am unsure if this is correct:

I have a sample size of 25 from a population where $\sigma^2$=6. The confidence interval for the mean is given as (5.37, 7.37).

I am asked to find the confidence coefficient for this interval.

So $p$ (assume this is p-hat) is 6.37. and if the interval is (p-w,p+w) then w is given as 1. These things are obvious.

Would I use $\frac{\sqrt6}{\sqrt{25}}$ = .49 to find that $7.37-6.37=1$ and $\frac{1}{.49}=2.04$

so (5.37,7.37) is (-2.04 sd, 2.04 sd)- correct?

If that is correct then I can say the confidence coefficient is the area left in either tail so it is about .0207?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your math by working out the problem, you were very close!

$$X_i\text{~}N(\mu, \sigma^2 = 6) \implies \bar{X}\text{~}N(\mu, \frac6n)$$
Our confidence interval is given by: 
$$P(\bar{X}\in (5.37,7.37)) = P(|\bar{X} - \mu| < 1)= P(\sqrt{\frac{n}{6}}|\bar{X} - \mu|<\sqrt{\frac{n}6}) = \alpha$$
$$\text{So we have a confidence interval of width } 2\cdot\sqrt\frac{25}{6} = 2\cdot(2.041...)$$
$$\text{Then }\alpha = 2\cdot\big(1-\Phi^{-1}\big(\sqrt\frac{25}{6}\big)\big) = \ ...$$